# Customize master page on modern/communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I know that with the SharePoint Online publishing site we can develop a site where we can have the exact layout of my designed mock-up. So my question is will we be able to customize on some of the default components, such as the branding of O365 and navigation on top, to what we want?

For instance, removing the branding or changing the designing of the navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, customizing master page is not supported on modern sites.

More information, you can refer to the MSDN article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites

Answer (score 1):

New capabilities are being released to enable customising elements of modern pages, via the [SharePoint Framework extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension).  So far the advice from Microsoft is we should only be targeting specific elements of a page [with page placeholders as recommended here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions).

The general advice around supported customisations on modern sites is they will be made through browser-side code only; we probably won't know what the master page looks like into the future.

Answer (score 1):

Good article. for activating Master pages, i followed this article to change the master page. http://sharepointsolutions-sudheer.blogspot.com/2020/04/custom-master-page-modern-site-sharepoint-online.html

and https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-custom-master-page-in-html-for-sharepoint-online/