# How to apply Master Page to SharePoint Online Site Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, custom-masterpage, sitepages

I have started using Office 365 recently. I liked the features of Site Pages where we can add Hero Webparts, Highlighted Content webparts etc.

However, I am struggling to apply my custom master page to these site pages. Is that restricted by Microsoft or I am missing any settings?

Kindly guide me here. I can successfully apply the master page to my publishing pages (site/sitename/Pages/).

Answer (score 1):

Custom master pages are currently not supported for "modern" pages.

**Documentation**: [Supported customizations for "modern" pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages)

Similar thread: [Customize master page on modern/communication site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230063/customize-master-page-on-modern-communication-site)