# Create Custom Master Page for "SharePoint Online"

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, master-page, customization

I'd like to know how to do it.

Is it possible to create such using the SharePoint Framework (SPFx)?

Comment: Are you trying to customize master page for "modern experience"?

Answer (score 1):

Custom master pages are *not supported* for "modern experience" in SharePoint online.

Here's Microsoft official documentation which might help you to understand this: [Supported customizations for "modern" pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages)

**Similar thread**: [Customize master page on modern/communication site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230063/customize-master-page-on-modern-communication-site)

---

For classic experience, you can try the solution given here: [Create A Custom Master Page In HTML For SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-custom-master-page-in-html-for-Sharepoint-online/)